# WPF Data Binding to Bool Property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

On MainWindow.xaml

```
<Label Content="{Binding ActEna,Mode=OneWay}"/>
<Button Content="Toggle" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

On MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public bool ActEna { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            ActEna=true;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ActEna = !ActEna;
        }
    }
```

When application was launched Label value is True.

When the user click's on Toggle button the label was not updating.

How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the data binding to work correctly. Have a look here, it explains it quite well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netcore-3.1 .

You would have something similar to this :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged

private bool _actEna;
public bool ActEna
{
   get
       {
        return _actEna; 
       }
   set
       {
        _actEna = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
       }

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ActEna = !ActEna;

} 
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  
private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")        
{  
   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));      
}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly, for OP if he wants to use it, or for others coming on this question